# gramex docker | running multiple instances within docker

Tags: docker, gramex

as per [gramex-install-doc](https://learn.gramener.com/guide/install/#docker-install) gramex could be started by running

```
# Run Gramex on port 9988
docker run --name gramex-instance -p 9988:9988 gramener/gramex
```

is it possible to start multiple `gramex` instances by changing `--name` parameter & different port numbers using `-p` parameter?
when I tried to start gramex by:

```
docker run --name gramex-test-port -p 9998:9998 gramener/gramex
```

in the console it was still printing:

```
INFO    13-Apr 18:21:41 __init__ PORT Listening on port 9988
```

can multiple gramex instances be started using gramex-docker-install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding you application's `gramex.yaml` with below entry:

```
app:
    listen:
        port: 9998
```

and then starting docker container at the application directory with below params is starting gramex at required port

```
docker run --name gramex-agri-prod -i -t -p 9998:9998 -v "$(pwd)":"$(pwd)" -w "$(pwd)"  gramener/gramex
```

Note: include `-d` param to run it as deamon process